# How to create Nullable fields/variables from WSDL instead of extra fields/variables

Tags: .net, wcf, wsdl

I am using wsdl.exe to convert a WSDL file and Types.xsd file into a C# file. The wsdl file specifies optional variables (`minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"`), and the generated .NET type handles this by created two fields - one for the variable (e.g. `status`) and one to let you know if it's specified (`statusSpecified`).

Is there a way to use the `wsdl` tool to only create one field that is `Nullable` (i.e. if not null, it is specified)? (If it helps, I think I can change the wsdl file to have `nillable="true"` elements.)

Is there a different, better tool that will generate .NET types from WSDL? I am using .NET 4, so it would be useful if the generated types took advantage of features like Nullable types.

NOTE: I just realized that I am using the wsdl tool from .NET 2 and that newer projects should use WCF for this stuff. Any pointers on the WCF way to get what I want?

Regarding WCF, [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/24/wsdl-first-development-with-wcf.aspx) pointed me in the direction of using the `svcutil` tool (which was already in my PATH, so I could just run it from the command line in the folder with the wsdl and xsd files like so: `svcutil *.wsdl *.xsd /language:C#`). Unfortunately, svcutil doesn't seem to do any better with using Nullable types instead of `xSpecified` variables.

Answer (score 1):

no, unless you modify your xsd schema.
[Read this article about xsd](http://www.dimuthu.org/blog/2008/08/18/xml-schema-nillabletrue-vs-minoccurs0/comment-page-1/)

If you have element with `minOccurs="0"` and `nillable="true"` it will still generate xSpecified field.

```
private System.Nullable<bool> x;

private bool xSpecified;
```

If you want field to be nullable then element in xsd needs `minOccurs="1"` and `nillable="true"`.

```
private System.Nullable<bool> x;
```

Difference between nullable and Specified:

- if field is nullable, then field will be serialized even if it's null: `<minzero xsi:nil="true"><minzero>`
- if field specified is false. then field will not be serialized.

Hope it helps :)